# Color Management: Monitor profile changed notification for Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, wcs, color-management

### The Short Version:

I’m looking for the Windows API equivalent of the Cocoa [`– windowDidChangeBackingProperties:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidChangeBackingProperties:) notification in the [`NSWindowDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol which is called when a window’s colorspace changes (when it’s moved to another monitor or when the monitor profile is change by the user).

**Does anyone know what the equivalent API would be on Windows?**

### The Long Version:

I’m developing an app that is fully color managed. As such I need to be notified when the monitor’s color profile is changed or when the application window is moved to a different screen. On the Mac side this is easy, I just implement the [`– windowDidChangeBackingProperties:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidChangeBackingProperties:) method for my window’s delegate and I’ll get notifications whenever the user drags the window to another monitor or whenever the global monitor profile is changed. Simple & easy. On the Windows side I don’t know how to get these notifications.

Currently I’m getting the monitor profile using the [`GetICMProfile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316948(v=vs.85).aspx) WCS ([Windows Color System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372446(v=vs.85).aspx)) function  when the app starts up. I need some notification for when the monitor profile changes.

**How do I receive monitor profile change notifications on Windows?**

Bonus points for a notification for when the application window is moved from one monitor to another. I’d hope that there exists a notification for that, but if there isn’t I can probably figure it out by monitoring window moves.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to query the color profile with `GetICMProfile()` in some specific messages (`WM_SHOWWINDOW`, `WM_ACTIVATE`, and `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`) and then to compare if the profile filename has changed (if the filename has changed, the current profile has changed too).

This is a shame, but it looks like the `HWND` doesn't receive a message when we change the color profile from the display settings, so the `WM_ACTIVE` partially solves that problem (when the window is clicked/activated, we can check if the color profile has changed).